# How to fix async/await error in flutter test?

Tags: flutter, async-await, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to write a test for my flutter App. The function for which I am writing the test returns a Future, therefore I am using await.

But as soon as any await statement is used I get the MissingPluginException Error.

I tried changing dependency version, but it doesn't help. Could not find anything on GitHub for Flutter Issues or StackOverFlow regarding this.

### check_app_version_test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import '../home.dart';

void main() {
  test('checkAppVersion', () async {
    expect(await checkAppVersionTest(true), true);
  });
}
```

### home.dart

```
String currentVersionString = await GetVersion.projectVersion;
Version currentVersion = Version.parse(currentVersionString);

Future<bool> checkAppVersionTest([bool test, Version latestVersion]) async {

...
  if (currentVersion < latestVersion) {
    updateRequired = true;
  }
...
return updateRequired

}
```

expected to work fine.

Getting error:

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on
>   channel plugins.flutter.io/package_info)
>   package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 300:7 
>   MethodChannel.invokeMethod   ===== asynchronous gap
>   ===========================   dart:async                                                _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError   package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart
>   MethodChannel.invokeMethod   ===== asynchronous gap
>   ===========================   dart:async                                                _asyncThenWrapperHelper   package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart
>   MethodChannel.invokeMethod   package:package_info/package_info.dart
>   38:17              PackageInfo.fromPlatform

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you simply have to install your pods.
Open up a terminal and navigate to your flutter directory.
CD into the iOS directory via `cd iOS/` and then run `pod install`

Now you should be able to run the project just fine.

Comment: This App is only specific to Android, I don't understand how that would help?

Comment: @sakina Flutter is Multi Platform. So it might not work for you. But It will probably work for IOS users

Answer (score 0):

Just terminate the app and hot restart the app.
As you added a dependency which requires a platform specific code to run through platform channel. You have to restart the app by terminating the current one.